# Documentation that states the effect of "special" with other characters in Gmail search

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Where can I find documentation that states the effect of "special" with other characters in Gmail search, for example "here | there".

I know:

[image]

(note "only") but I was surprised and dismayed to see failure of a search expression containing | (bar) (presumably "like" those listed characters) but not **only** | (bar) e.g. "here | there".

Answer (score 3):

## Short answer

There is no official documentation so you should look at user created documentation.

## Extended answer

The Gmail documentation:

- for end-users can be found at http://support.google.com
- for developers can be found at http://developers.google.com/gmail

Both places point readers looking for advanced search operators to https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en

Neither of previous sites states the effects of special characters with other characters but [Sensesul](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/207/senseful) made a great blog post about that. See - [How Gmail Filter Email-Matching Works](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/07/how-gmail-filter-email-matching-works.html) dated on Wednesday, July 14, 2010.

According to [Aʟ E.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/354/a%CA%9F-e) on [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/52829/88163), the [Gmail Search](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6593) official help article used to say that

> Gmail doesn't recognize special search characters like square brackets, parentheses, currency symbols, the ampersand, the pound sign, and asterisks

But the above statement was removed from the current version.

### String quote enclosed

`""` are used to search for an exact word or phrase. The official help article about it doesn't mention that special characters are ignored, but they are.

### Regarding the pipe as search operator

The oldest dated post/web page that I found that mention the use of the pipe character `|` as search operator is [Gmail search operators work in filters, too](http://lifehacker.com/166172/gmail-search-operators-work-in-filters-too) by Gina Trapani dated on 4/10/06 12:30pm, but this mentions the use of double pipe `||`

Another old post that mentions the use of single pipe `|` is [Ten Must-Have Gmail Filters Available for Download](http://lifehacker.com/5167829/ten-must-have-gmail-filters-available-for-download) by Gina Trapani dated on 3/11/09 9:00am.

## See also

- [Create Gmail filter that contains a special character](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52828/create-gmail-filter-that-contains-a-special-character) dated on asked Dec 5 '13 at 18:44

Comment: "the above statement was removed from the current version." Figures, since certainly it is not currently true for |. Gmail recognises the | of "here | there", as proven by the fact the results differ w.r.t "here there".

Answer (score 2):

What I found is that you can figure out what Google does by creating a label with the text you want to query, then click on the label and it will perform a search of messages with that label.  For the characters I was interested in "() ", it ends up replacing them with dashes "-" so it seems it "normalizes" the search query, which explains why your particular search would not work.