# How to search/filter with keyword that match all given characters?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-search

I want to create a filter to add a label to all emails that mention me in other apps like Jira, Bitbucket, etc.

Based on [Official Gmail Documentation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en), it says to search for an exact word or phrase    I must put the keyword inside double quotes.

I tried `"@Muhammad Dyas Yaskur"` but it shows an email that doesn't have `@` like below:
[image]

I only want to find all the emails that exactly have all of my keywords (including `@`) like below:

[image]

Is it possible using Gmail to filter that?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. I suggest you to look first at [Amit Agarwal's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/31448/88163) from 2012 (it's one of the answer of the [duplicate target](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/31322/88163)). It suggest the use a script. If you want to learn why, you might have to read other answers. The summary is that Gmail search is limited, you might use email-clients, third party tools that offer more features or use Google Apps Script / Gmail API.

Comment: I just added another duplicate target also with a [Amit Agarwal's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/80665/88163) with a script for doing an exact search in the Gmail mailbox.